# How to remove fisheye in PhotoScan Pro?

Tags: photo-editing, image-processing, fisheye, gopro

I am trying to build a 3D model of a site in CA using Photoscan Pro. The images were taken by 3DR solo drone GoPro camera. I need to process the image in Photoscan, however, I am having trouble with the fisheye, I couldn't find a way to remove it using this software. I have about 6000 images, so removing fisheye for single images in GoPro studio is going to be time consuming. I was able to remove the fisheye for individual image in GoPro studio but not for the entire file of 6000 images.

Does anyone know how to remove fisheye in Photoscan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I have not used PhotoScan before, I have no experience with the software</sup>

According to this [thread at AgiSoft's forums](http://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=3222.0), you just have to tell PhotoScan what camera/lens you are using, under **Tools > Camera Calibration**.

The rest of the discussion thread has some links to people's results of mapping GoPro images to buildings and sculptures, so it sounds like it can all be done in PhotoScan without manual or external processing.